# Why anonymous classes aren't included in languages such as C# and Dart?

Tags: c#, java, dart, anonymous-types

I write a lot of code in Java, and always use anonymous classes. They allows you write concise code without boilerplate.

However, many modern languages, like C# and Dart don't include them. Why they aren't included there? What's so bad about them? Are there any blog post or articles where languages' where authors describe why they excluded them from these languages?

Comment: C# *has* anonymous types.  It just doesn't have anonymous interface implementations.

Comment: I don't get why this question is being downvoted and voted to be closed. He just need a light, perhaps those who are downvoting would care to explain him what he got wrong about this topic.

Comment: You always use anonymous classes? That's an overkill. There is a reason that actual classes exist. Anonymous classes are usually used in a small scope, most usually in continuous extension methods with lambda expressions, when it really is a waste creating a whole class for it.

Comment: @Havenard The explanation is in the description of the closing reason.

Comment: @Havenard The question isn't appropriate for SO.  Regardless of it's quality, it's neither a question that *can* be answered effectively by this audience (we aren't party to why the language designers did what they did, we can only guess) and guessing isn't particularly productive.  SO is designed for *practical* programming problems.

Comment: If you ask just about classes with `anonymity` as in `Java`, the answer is simple: It's not necessary. Such classes in `Java` for the lack `closures` (anonymous actions). Without these classes `Java` could not be effective. `C#` and `Dart` effective in this case without these `Java-like anonymous classes` with closures (`Action` in `C#` and `Function` in `Dart`).

Comment: @Servy If you can't answer a question effectively just don't touch it. There are people involved in language design who read SO and they might help. Instead you closed the question, and I won't be able to get an answer from them.